# Сохранение в Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookie

У меня есть форма и я хочу, чтобы значение каждого элемента (допустим, `textarea`) после его изменения сохранялось с cookie с именем, созвучным с name элемента, или с входным параметром функции (например, `saveForm(12)`). Как надолго? До закрытия браузера.

Попрошу реализовать это с помощью JavaScript посредством событий (`onkeypress` или `onchange` или `onblur`).

Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: А вам действительно [это так необходимо][1]?

[1]:http://www.codeart.ru/2010/01/20/ogranicheniya-na-cookie/

Comment: Народ совсем оборзел:)
http://hashcode.ru/questions/57653/сохранение-данных-в-форме?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#57734

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Заполнение списка и запись в cookie](http://javascript.ru/blog/invem/Zapolnenie-spiska-zapis-cookie)

Comment: Не то. У меня немного другая потребность